# updating dictionary inside list of dicts, when comparing two another list of dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two list of dictionaries and when a certain key matches, i want it to append the dict in the first list to the second, but when the dictionary gets big, it takes a very long time. Is there a faster way to do it?

```
with open('tables', 'rb') as fp:
    tables = pickle.load(fp)
# embedding
for table in tables:
    filename = table + "_constraints"
    with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
        fkeys = pickle.load(fp)
    if fkeys and len(fkeys) == 1:
        key = fkeys[0][1]
        rkey = fkeys[0][2]
        rtable = fkeys[0][3]
        filename = table + ".json"
        with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
            child = list(json.load(fp))
        filename = rtable + ".json"
        with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
            parent = list(json.load(fp))
        for dict in child:
            for rdict in parent:
                if dict[key] == rdict[rkey]:
                    if "embed_"+table not in rdict:
                        rdict["embed_"+table] = []
                    del dict[key]
                    rdict["embed_"+table].append(dict)
                    break
```

input example would be:

```
tables = [child, parent]
child = [{child_id : 1, child_name : matthew , parent_id: 1},
         {child_id : 2, child_name : luke , parent_id: 1},
         {child_id : 3, child_name : mark , parent_id: 2}]
parent = [{parent_id:1, parent_name: john},
          {parent_id:2, parent_name: paul}, 
          {parent_id:3, parent_name: titus}]
```

output would be:

```
parent = [{parent_id:1, parent_name: john, child_embed:[{child_id : 1, child_name : matthew },{child_id : 2, child_name : luke}]},
          {parent_id:2, parent_name: paul, chiled_embed : [{child_id : 3, child_name : mark}]}, 
          {parent_id:3, parent_name: titus}]
```

Comment: So whats your question?

Comment: Sorry, i wanted to know if there is a faster way to do it. edited it in.

Comment: Welcome to SO. *"Certain key"* is known only to you unless you describe here. What is that key? Give sample input and it's expected output.

Comment: edit the example in

Comment: Your main issue with speed is that you are using lists where you should be using dicts. You have unique ids for both parents and children so you should have dicts keyed to those ids. Then you can lookup in constant time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make a loop like this:

```
for dict in child:
    for rdict in parent:
```

you are setting up an O(n²) operation. For every child you can potentially search through every parent. Given 1000 kids and 1000 parents that's of the order of a million loops. Granted you can break early, but it doesn't change the growth rate of the function with respect to the number in the list.

You should take the time to make an object that lets you find what  you need at the same speed regardless of how big it is. In Python that's the `dict`. You can turn your parent list into a dict with one loop through it:

```
>>  parent_d = {d['parent_id']: {'name': d['parent_name']} for d in parent}
>>  print(parent_d)

{1: {'name': 'john'}, 2: {'name': 'paul'}, 3: {'name': 'titus'}}
```

This lets you lookup parents without looping through the whole list every time:

```
>> parent_d[1]
{'name': 'john'}
```

With that in place you can loop once through the kids and add them to the parent (using `setdefault` is a handy way to initialize a list if the key is new):

```
for d in child:
    parent = parent_d[d['parent_id']]
    parent.setdefault('child_embed', []).append({'child_id' : d['child_id'], 'child_name' : d['child_name'] })
```

Now you have a clear dictionary with all the info keyed to parent:

```
{ 1: {'name': 'john','child_embed': [{'child_id': 1, 'child_name': 'matthew'},{'child_id': 2, 'child_name': 'luke'}]},
  2: {'name': 'paul', 'child_embed': [{'child_id': 3, 'child_name': 'mark'}]},
  3: {'name': 'titus'}}
```

This is a nice format to work with. If you need to get back to a list to match your old format, you can use a list comprehension:

```
>> [{'parent_id':i, **rest} for i, rest in parent_d.items()]

[{'parent_id': 1,
  'name': 'john',
  'child_embed': [{'child_id': 1, 'child_name': 'matthew'},
   {'child_id': 2, 'child_name': 'luke'}]},
 {'parent_id': 2,
  'name': 'paul',
  'child_embed': [{'child_id': 3, 'child_name': 'mark'}]},
 {'parent_id': 3, 'name': 'titus'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need if I am reading the question correctly...

```
for entry in child:
    p_id = entry['parent_id']
    parent_update = [x for x in parent if x['parent_id'] == p_id][0]
    position = parent.index(parent_update)
    del entry['parent_id']
    if 'child_embed' in list(parent_update.keys()):
        parent_update['child_embed'] = parent_update['child_embed'] + [entry]
    else:
        parent_update['child_embed'] = [entry]
    parent[position] = parent_update

print(parent)
```

which gives:

```
[{'parent_id': 1, 'parent_name': 'john', 'child_embed': [{'child_id': 1, 'child_name': 'matthew'}, {'child_id': 2, 'child_name': 'luke'}]}, {'parent_id': 2, 'parent_name': 'paul', 'child_embed': [{'child_id': 3, 'child_name': 'mark'}]}, {'parent_id': 3, 'parent_name': 'titus'}]
```